# Want to call div but in new line javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

i want to call div from javascript but the result like stack

page 1

```
     <script>               
        function jvbab(content) {
        var request = $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "ceking.php",   
                data: {bab: content}
               });

            request.done( function( msg ) {
                $("#myboxmin").html(msg); 
            });
            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });
        }
        </script>
```

page 2

```
    <script>               
    function jvpasal(content) {
    var request = $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "cektopik.php",   
            data: {pasal: content}
           });

        request.done( function( msg ) {

            $("#mybox").html(msg); 
        });
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    }
    </script>
```

if i run this the div stack on it

like

```
<div id="myboxmin">
   <div id="mybox">
   </div>
</div>
```

i want to, that two div separate ..

```
<div id="myboxmin">
</div>

<div id="mybox">
</div>
```

May you know solution to separate that div ? thanks

my php i put like this ..

```
<?php
session_start();
$bab = $_GET['bab'];
$_SESSION['bab']=$bab;

include '../koneksi.php';
?>

<html>
<head>

            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta name="keywords" content="" />
            <meta name="description" content="" />
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Klasifikasi Al-Quran</title>

            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

            <script type="text/javascript" src="sitemapstyler.js"></script>
            <link href="../css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery-ui.css" />

            <script>               
            function jvpasal(content) {
            var request = $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: "cektopik.php",   
                    data: {pasal: content}
                   });

                request.done( function( msg ) {

                    $("#mybox").html(msg); 
                });
                request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                });
            }
            </script>

</head>
<body>
    <br><br><h1></h1><br><br>
    <h3>Pasal</h3><br>
    <?php                 

    $r=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT id_pasal,nama_pasal FROM nama_pasal_topik
                    WHERE id_bab = '$bab' ") or die (mysql_error());

       while($rr=mysql_fetch_array($r)){                   
             $nama_pasal=$rr['nama_pasal'];
             $id_pasal=$rr['id_pasal'];?>

             <a href="#"  id="pasal" name="pasal" onclick="jvpasal('<?php echo $id_pasal; ?>');" ><?php echo $nama_pasal; ?></a>
             <br>  
       <?php } ?>


    <div class="mybox">
    m
    </div> <!--tutup mybox-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find `myboxmin` parent and append a new div

```
 request.done( function( msg ) {    
      $("#myboxmin").parent().append(msg); 
 });
```

Comment: its work .. but wait .. div was separate, but the msg out of the div

Comment: <div id="mybox"></div>
data here ///

should be 
<div id="mybox">
data
</div>

Comment: Check with your php script if its sending response correctly.

Comment: i put php like that .. @vicky